# custom mysqli class has an error with php 5.4?

Tags: mysqli, php, strict

I just had my web-server upgrade to php 5.4 and am getting errors on my sites that use my database class which extends from the built in mysqli. the error is on the last line of my class and despite the error message everything is working fine....

the error message:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of yamiko_mysqli::connect() should be compatible with mysqli::connect($host = NULL, $user = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL, $port = NULL, $socket = NULL) in /home/markwe6/public_html/_php/yamiko_mysqli.php on line 109
```

and the class is:

```
class Yamiko_mysqli extends mysqli
{
    public $host='localhost';
    public $user='markwe6_yamiko';
    public $pass='1chrysanthemum!';
    public $db='markwe6_cp';
    public $result=NULL;#stores most recent result

    /*
     * 
     */
    public function __construct($auto=TRUE)
    {
        if($auto)
        {
            return $this->connect();
        }else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    /*
     * 
     */
    public function connect($auto=TRUE, $user=NULL, $pass=NULL, $host=NULL, $db=NULL)
    {
        if($auto)
        {
            parent::__construct($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
            return $this->check_error();
        }else
        {
            parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);
            return $this->check_error();
        }
    }

    /*
     * 
     */
    public function query($sql)
    {
        $result=parent::query($sql);
        if($this->check_error())
            return FALSE;
        $this->result=$result;
        return $result;
    }

    /*
     * 
     */
    private function check_error()
    {
        if($this->connect_error!=NULL)
        {
            $GLOBALS['yamiko']->set_error('yamiko_myslqi connection error: '.$this->connect_error);
            return FALSE;
        }elseif ($this->error!=NULL)
        {
            $GLOBALS['yamiko']->set_error('yamiko_myslqi error: '.$this->error);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}#this is line 109....-_-
```

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand? -or- What is your question?

Comment: i dont understand the error at all...the class is working just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> custom mysqli class has an error with php 5.4?

No, not an error, but a strict standard warning. If you consider a warning an error, then yes, your custom mysqli class has an error with php 5.4.

The strict standard warning reads as follows:

If you ever intent to extend from the base class. the declaration of the connect function must match with that one of the base class:

```
mysqli::connect($host = NULL, $user = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL, $port = NULL, $socket = NULL)
```

In your case it does not:

```
Yamiko_mysqli::connect($auto=TRUE, $user=NULL, $pass=NULL, $host=NULL, $db=NULL)
```

As you can see, both have different parameters.

The fix in your case is rather trivial, you just re-use the first parameter, if `NULL` you provide the class'es own default values:

```
/*
 * 
 */
public function connect($host = NULL, $user = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL, $port = NULL, $socket = NULL)
{
    if($host === NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        return $this->check_error();
    }else
    {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $password , $database, $port, $socket);
        return $this->check_error();
    }
}
```

Take care that port and socket is missing with your default config.

Comment: From showing? Disable [`display_errors`](http://php.net/display_errors) probably. Otherwise, you should use the same parameters or just don't extend from `mysqli`. I've updated the answer as well so it contains more info.

Comment: @yamikoWebs: Just added a simple fix, just seeing what you need.

Comment: yes thank you. sorry about the delay to accept answer I haven't been on SO for a few days.